# Как сделать перехват всего что попадает в консоль?

Tags: javascript, консоль

Допустим у меня есть какая-то функция, которая будет выводить `alert()`:

```
var foo(err){
   alert(err)
}
```

И допустим где-то в коде появляется ошибка с из-за неопределенной переменной и попытке доступа к ее свойству:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`

Я могу это сообщение видеть в консоли, но как написать обработчик, либо eventListener для консоли? т.е. я хочу передать сообщение с ошибкой в консоли в мою функцию `foo()`, при этом я не должен оборачивать нужный участок кода условиями или юзать `try catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нашел ответ, может кому-нибудь пригодится

```
window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
    var error = e.error;
   foo(error);
});
```

Comment: По хорошему, это никогда не должно работать. Свой код - исправьте, чужой - ловите `try...catch`.

Comment: @Other всмысле никогда? Любая возникающая ошибка, это событие, и как раз таки событие `error`, с чего вдруг оно не должно срабатывать?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, это событие вызывается только если ошибку **не** перехватывают. Если она перехвачена, событие не вызывается. Попробуйте проверить сами, если не верите.

Comment: @Other В том и смысл сего акта вандализма, чтобы логировать необработанные ошибки. Легко сказать: «исправьте, ловите `try...catch`», а так ли просто это реализовать, как исправлять ошибку, когда ты о ней даже не подозреваешь?? Спасибо @sanu0074.